# How to detect the presence of the MicroSoft Visual C++ 2005,2008 and 2010 redistributable package

Tags: windows, visual-c++, registry, redistributable

Can anyone please suggest me how can I query for the registry entry of MicroSoft Visual C++ 2005,2008(x86) and 2010(x86) Redistributable. For example to get the Notepad++ I used the below query.

**reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++**

If it present will get errorlevel as 0, if not will get 1.

Same way I just want to findout for 2005,2008 and 2010. Am not able to see any names like VisualC++ 2005,VisualC++ 2008 etc in the regedit list.

Am suspecting that they might have used some registry keys behalf of name of the software.Please suggest me how can I get the entries.

Am currently using Windows 2008.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: This is the job of the redist installer, not yours.  Which already knows how to deal with the many revisions that were deployed as service packs or security updates.  Just run it, it will very quickly complete when the machine already has an up-to-date or newer version installed.

Comment: Hi, Am looking by using reg query command.I can see the entry of 2005,08,10 in windows 7, but not in the windows 2008 OS.I used regedit to verify.Thanks For your reply.

Comment: This is the entry of VC++ 2008 in windows 7. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\D20352A90C039D93DBF6126ECE614057